# Only allowing a function to run n times with wrapper function

Tags: javascript, wrapper, execute

I need to make a wrapper function to invoke a function `multiply` with a given number `num` of times to allow the `multiply` to execute. `nTimes(num,2)` Then assign to `runTwice`  -- `runTwice` can be any function that invoke the `nTimes` function which given a different `num` input--

In my case, for simplicity, I am only allowing it to run 2 times `num=2`
If we run the `runTwice` function the first time and the second time it will return the result of `multiply` function calculated with the inputs for `multiply`.  Any invocation after the second time will not run the `multiply` function but will return the latest result of the `multiply` function.

Here is my implementation using an object to keep track of how many times we have execute the function, the max number allowed to execute and the latest result of `multiply`

```
 'use strict'
//use a counter object to keep track of counts, max number allowed to run and latest result rendered
let counter = {
    count:0,
    max: 0,
    lastResult: 0
};

let multiply = function(a,b){
    if(this.count<this.max){
        this.count++;
        this.lastResult = a*b;
        return a*b;
    }else{
        return this.lastResult;
    }
}

// bind the multiply function to the counter object
multiply = multiply.bind(counter);

let nTimes=function(num,fn){
    this.max = num;
    return fn;
};

// here the nTimes is only executed ONE time, we will also bind it with the counter object
let runTwice = nTimes.call(counter,3,multiply);

console.log(runTwice(1,3)); // 3
console.log(runTwice(2,3)); // 6
console.log(runTwice(3,3)); // 6
console.log(runTwice(4,3)); // 6
```

Note that I have altered the simple `multiply` quite a bit and bind it the `counter`object to make it work. Also using call on `nTimes` to bind `counter` object.

What can I do to implement the same result with a wrapper function but less alteration to the simple `multiply` function?

Let's say the `multiply` function is very simple:

```
let multiply = function(a,b){ return a*b };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nina's answer is great. Here's an alternative, with code that might look slightly easier to read:

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

function executeMaxTimes(max, fn) {
  let counter = 0, lastResult;
  return (...args) => counter++ < max 
    ? lastResult = fn(...args) 
    : lastResult;
}

const multiplyMaxTwice = executeMaxTimes(2, multiply);

console.log(multiplyMaxTwice(1, 3)); // 3
console.log(multiplyMaxTwice(2, 3)); // 6
console.log(multiplyMaxTwice(3, 3)); // 6
console.log(multiplyMaxTwice(4, 3)); // 6
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand this. So when we assign to `multiplyMaxTwice`, the executeMaxTimes is executed, only for one time.  Then when every time we invoke the `multiplyMaxTwice` the returned function will be invoked that makes the counter increase each time we invoked.  Is this the logic?

Comment: @MingHuang Actually, check my last edit for a slightly clearer version (`counter` defined as a normal variable). Basically, `executeMaxTimes` returns a function that compares `counter` with `max` and return either the result of `fn`, or the last result registered (`lastResult`). So, every time `multiplyMaxTwice` is called, that returned function checks that condition with an increased counter. First time `counter` is 0 (which is < `max`) so it returns the result of `fn` (`multiply` here), then 1 (same), then 2 which is not < `max` so `lastResult` is returned, same for subsequent calls.

Comment: changing value inside the ternary statement or if statement is very cool trick.  I have never use it like that before.  
One more question, it seems the `lastResult` in your code was never declared but you can just assign value to it.  What is happening there?

Comment: @Jeto You never declare `lastResult` this will fail strict mode

Comment: @MingHuang You're right (so is nick zoum), I actually forgot to declare it, sorry about that! Just edited the answer.

Comment: Great, now I can go to my interview and hope they ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a closure over the count and the last value and check count and decrement and store the last result.

```js
const
    multiply = (a, b) => a * b,
    maxCall = (fn, max, last) => (...args) => max && max-- ? last = fn(...args) : last,
    mult3times = maxCall(multiply, 3);

console.log(mult3times(2, 3));
console.log(mult3times(3, 4));
console.log(mult3times(4, 5));
console.log(mult3times(5, 6));
console.log(mult3times(6, 7));
```

Comment: The code works but I have a hard time understanding what is `last = max && max-- ` doing??

Comment: this is part of the check of the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), where max is checked and if not zero, then `max` is decremented and the result of the function call assigned. if `max` is zero, then `last` is assigned and returned.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how both Nina and Jeto have answered your question, here is a simple and similar way to do it that also keeps a history of all the results in case you want to get them at a later time.

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

function runMaxNTimes(num, callBack) {
  var results = new Array(num);
  var callTimes = 0;
  return function(...params) {
    return results.length > callTimes ?
      results[callTimes++] = callBack(...params) :
      results[callTimes - 1];
  };
}

var runTwice = runMaxNTimes(2, multiply);

console.log(runTwice(1, 3)); // 3
console.log(runTwice(2, 3)); // 6
console.log(runTwice(3, 3)); // 6
console.log(runTwice(4, 3)); // 6
```